# EAGLE: can't delete wire in tDocu layer

Tags: pcb, eaglecad

I'm designing a board that links sets of three Anderson PowerPole connectors to each other.

I traced the physical outline of the PowerPoles in the tDocu layer, but originally I did it incorrectly. I deleted the original wire in tDocu and drew a new one. In the package editor, it looks correect:

[image: the package viewed from the package editor, with the correct rectangle in tDocu]

but in the layout editor, and when previewing the package from the layout editor, it has retained a portion of the original, incorrect rectangle (the thicker one):

[image: the package as viewed from the layout editor, with the remnant incorrect tDocu rectangle overlapping the correct one]

Is this a common problem? Or am I doing something obviously wrong? I'm fairly new to EAGLE.

I have the library, board, and schematic files in a GitHub repo [here](https://github.com/lychrel/powerpolePCB).

Comment: The different editors have independent layer controls. Perhaps the package editor isn't displaying all layers?

Comment: @bitsmack interesting. I can check on that. I did draw both in the same layer in the package editor, however. It's also interesting how I apparently succeeded in deleting part of the original rectangle, just not all of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you modify a package or symbol that is already in use in a board or schematic, you have to update the library so that the changes will take place on your current design (Library > Update... / Update all):

[image]

Depending on the changes you made, Eagle will suggest you to run DRC/ERC due to the modifications.

You can update the specific library you modified, but I usually use "Update all" cause it is faster.

Comment: thanks so much! That fixed it. DRC threw around 250 default dimension errors, but those were intentional -- I'm placing copper pads over dimension holes to comply with manufacturer design stipulations for plated slots

Comment: Another interesting point: even though I didn't see it with all layers displayed, if I delete-clicked around where the old footprint was supposed to be, incrementally, and updated, this actually deleted it, piece by piece. So the wire had certainly moved Somewhere haha